# PHP Paginaciones con index 0

Tags: php, array, paginación

Necesito listar resultados por páginas; Mi array contiene X cantidad de resultados, sin embargo no consigo que el index de la lista aumente en un valor de 10 iniciando desde 0.

Por ejemplo:

```
Pagina = 1
Inicio = 0
Fin = 10
```

Hasta ahí vamos bien, la cuestión es cuando el valor de la página aumenta, deja de ser 1 y ahora es 2 o 3+;

Si la página es 2 debería iniciar desde el 11 y si es 3 debería iniciar desde el 22 ya que no estaríamos contando el 21 porque ya lo hemos mostrado en la página anterior.

Lo reduje un poco más:

```
$limit = 10;
$from = ((intval($page)*$limit)-$limit);
$end = ($from+$limit);
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el código?

Comment: no hacemos tarea solo te ayudamos con los errores de tu codigo
por favor pasate por la seccion como [preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ya que estas con php podes usar esta libreria para paginaciones PHPPaging.lib.php, desde el archivo de configuracion de la libreria podes especificar cada cuantos datos haga la paginacion por ejemplo, verifica la documentacion, con dos o 3 lineas tenes la tabla y la paginacion armada

Comment: @Optimae El codigo es justo lo que no conseguía, pero utilicé matemáticas y lo resolví, me costó un poco.

Comment: @Juan Es interesante lo que hoy en día hacen las librerías, pero para que incluir todo un fichero para una ejecución sencilla, ya les comparto debajo la solución que hice.